# Sitecore: How to add new language in the Client Language selection?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

In the User Manager, you can define a Client Language and Content Language.

1. What's the difference between Client and Content language ?
2. Which type of language could be used if you need to check the user language to send some newsletter or visualize the web site in their own language ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The client language is used for the language of all texts in the Sitecore client, like the name of the command in the ribbon. The content language is the language that is default when the user logs in into the Sitecore client. The default language that is used when the user edits or creates new Sitecore items.
2. The content language is the language that needs to be checked when visualizing content in the web or newsletter.

Comment: Thank you for those clarification. It was unclear as the Language field, visible as a property of the User (User Manager), was not shown when i was selecting the content language. So I have to build my code like  Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.ContentLanguage. And I will find the language associated for the user who will receive the newsletter and visualize the web site. Thank you.